# I am facing a issue in my project which is created in codeigniter,

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am facing a issue in my project which is build in codeigniter, I am facing auto-logout problem and when I see log(error-log) file I found error the error are following:-

> ERROR - 2017-11-15 16:15:50 --> Severity: Warning --> unlink(X:\xampp\tmp\ci_sessionboq544svmdme7blb7djjh1h92tnflmk7): Permission denied X:\xampp\htdocs\nabet-bmo\Code_v1\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php 320
>
> ERROR - 2017-11-15 16:15:50 --> Severity: Warning --> session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed X:\xampp\htdocs\nabet-bmo\Code_v1\system\libraries\Session\Session.php 720

Please help to resolve this problem

Comment: The issue will arise only in windows and when ajax. No problem will raise when in production server (linux)

Comment: CI does not have permissions to write the session. Chown or chmod the directory.

Comment: you are right, Mr Rejoanul Alam, I am facing problem while using ajax mostly, but how can I resolve it.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with AJAX or Windows; @JimWright gave the answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the config.php file you MUST set sess_save_path to a valid path. It was initially set to NULL. I have mine set to:

Now the sessions are being saved in this folder and can be unlinked when needed to

change application > config > config.php

```
$config['sess_save_path'] =  BASEPATH . 'cache/';
```

Comment: Glad to help :)